# Program with malloc: why can't Eva prove \valid(p)?

Tags: frama-c

How can I verify this C program using Frama-C?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *p = malloc(2);
  char s[2];
  p[0] = 0;
  s[0] = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run Frama-C 17 (Chlorine) on it, more specifically the Eva plug-in, I get:

```
$ frama-c -val t.c
[kernel] Parsing t.c (with preprocessing)
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
[value] Computing initial state
[value] Initial state computed
[value:initial-state] Values of globals at initialization
  __fc_heap_status ∈ [--..--]
  __fc_random_counter ∈ [--..--]
  __fc_rand_max ∈ {32767}
  __fc_mblen_state ∈ [--..--]
  __fc_mbtowc_state ∈ [--..--]
  __fc_wctomb_state ∈ [--..--]
[value] t.c:5: allocating variable __malloc_main_l5
[value:alarm] t.c:7: Warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(p + 0);
[value] done for function main
[value] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[value:final-states] Values at end of function main:
  __fc_heap_status ∈ [--..--]
  p ∈ {{ &__malloc_main_l5[0] }}
  s[0] ∈ {0}
   [1] ∈ UNINITIALIZED
  __retres ∈ {0}
  __malloc_main_l5[0] ∈ {0}
          [1] ∈ UNINITIALIZED
```

Apparently Eva plugin knows about the size of the allocated chunk with
malloc. And it correctly infers the write to `s[0]` as valid (if I try writing to `s[3]`, for instance, it detects the error).

But how could I tell it to discharge the `\valid(p+0)` goal?

I also tried the WP plugin, but it says that allocation is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that **by default, in Eva, `malloc` can fail**. To avoid this, choose one the following:

- use option `-no-val-alloc-returns-null`, which supposes that `malloc` never fails;
- patch the code to add a test, e.g. `if (!p) exit(1);`

#### Detailed explanation

The fact that there are 2 possible executions after the `malloc` is not immediately visible in the command-line. The GUI sometimes helps when inspecting such cases, but we can also add a call to `Frama_C_show_each(p)` after the call to `malloc`:

```
  char *p = malloc(2);
  Frama_C_show_each_p(p);
  ...
```

Now, after running `frama-c -val`, we get the following line:

```
[value] mall.c:6: Frama_C_show_each_p: {{ NULL ; &__malloc_main_l5 }}
```

The two different possibilies (`malloc` failed and returned `NULL`; or `malloc` succeeded and returned a new base) are considered by the analysis.

The alarm `Warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(p + 0);` refers to the first case, in which the property is **invalid**. The analysis stops for this branch, which makes it harder to see what happened, since afterwards we have a single branch, just as we had expected.